# Single Table or multiple table- normalisation

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a question that may be simple for you to answer

I have an image table below

An image can have multiple sizes- is it better practice to have three tables

One table for image details
another table that joins image_details to image_paths and another table- image_sizes that joins to image paths.

Or is it best to put all the image sizes in the image table. In effect I have one image but in different sizes. Looking for the best option for optimisation. All images will have each image sizes so there is no redundancy in the future for some images not having certain sizes. I was unsure if it was best to use another table though in case we add other sizes. However i could add another column to the image table for a new image size

**Image_table**

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `warrington_main`.`image` (  
  `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  
  `user_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,  
  `alias_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,  
  `address_id` BIGINT(20) NULL ,  
  `geolocation_id` BIGINT(20) NULL ,  
  `camera_id` MEDIUMINT(8) NULL ,  
  `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,  
  `description` VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL ,  
  `main_image` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,  
  `thumbnail_image` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,  
  `thumbnail_image_medium` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,  
  `thumbnail_image_small` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,  
  `thumbnail_image_gallery` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,  
  `hits` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,  
  `show_comment` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL ,  
  `feature_in_gallery` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL ,  
  `created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,  
  `date_taken` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,  
  `updated_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,  
  `updated_by` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,  
  `approved` ENUM('Inprocess','Yes','No') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Inprocess' ,  
  `visible` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,  
  `account_type_created` ENUM('S','Y', 'G', 'FL', 'FB') NOT NULL ,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,  
  UNIQUE INDEX `alias_title` (`alias_title` ASC) ,  
  INDEX `title` (`title` ASC) ,  
  INDEX `approved` (`approved` ASC) ,  
  INDEX `visible` (`visible` ASC) ,  
  INDEX `feature_in_gallery` (`feature_in_gallery` ASC) ,  
  INDEX `fk_image_image_user1_idx` (`user_id` ASC) ,  
  INDEX `fk_image_camera1_idx` (`camera_id` ASC) ,  
  INDEX `fk_image_address1_idx` (`address_id` ASC) ,  
  INDEX `fk_image_geolocation1_idx` (`geolocation_id` ASC) ,  
  INDEX `fk_image_user1_idx` (`updated_by` ASC) ,  
  CONSTRAINT `fk_image_image_user1`  
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )  
    REFERENCES `warrington_main`.`user` (`id` )  
    ON DELETE NO ACTION  
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,  
  CONSTRAINT `fk_image_camera1`  
    FOREIGN KEY (`camera_id` )    
    REFERENCES `warrington_main`.`camera` (`id` )  
    ON DELETE NO ACTION  
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,  
  CONSTRAINT `fk_image_address1`  
    FOREIGN KEY (`address_id` )  
    REFERENCES `warrington_main`.`address` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION  
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_image_geolocation1`  
    FOREIGN KEY (`geolocation_id` )  
    REFERENCES `warrington_main`.`geolocation` (`id` )  
    ON DELETE NO ACTION  
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,  
  CONSTRAINT `fk_image_user1`    
    FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by` )    
    REFERENCES `warrington_main`.`user` (`id` )    
    ON DELETE NO ACTION    
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)    
ENGINE = InnoDB    
AUTO_INCREMENT = 23162    
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One table for image details another table that joins image_details to image_paths and another table- image_sizes that joins to image paths.

This is not normalization and is referred to as [Vertical Partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29) where you want the primary details of an object to be present in one table and the auxiliary details that occupy more space (in general) and are not part of general filtering criteria are moved to a different table. This is done to reduce the size of each record of the first table so that there will be more number of records in each database page and hence less number of pages to go through during filtering, less IO and faster search ability.

In your case, it seems fine to retain all attributes of an image in a single table.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should go for normalization where you use multiple tables and don't store the same information at more than one place. This redundancy avoids number of data issues later in any application life cycle.

So in your case `IMAGE_SIZE` should be another table with `IMAGE_ID` as foreign key defined.

```
IMAGE
    ID
    IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES

IMAGE_SIZE
    ID
    IMAGE_ID
    SIZE_ATTRIBUTES 

 IMAGE_PATH
    IMAGE_ID or IMAGE_SIZE_ID (depends)
    PATH
```

Comment: Where is the redunancy of data?

Comment: If sizes comes in a single table then image data will be redundant as multiple rows will have the same image information.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong - I read it as his one table solution would look like this: `ImageID | Detail1 | Detail2 .. | SmallImageURL | MediumImageURL ...` where each ImageID would have all of the ImageURL's present. I don't see the redunancy there

Comment: if every value is different though there is no redundancy- i.e. if one image_details can belong to one image and an image is different path for each size then i should never have redundant information. However i am unsure if keeping in one table goes against the first rule of normalisation. However no joins may speed up the query?

Comment: a column needs adding each time in this instance- is that not good, just trying to find best option

Comment: Yes a DDL change each time - which is why it's important he ask how often that will occur. If he thinks it will be rather rare, why not.

Comment: will be rare maximum of say ten image sizes- prescott you think best in one or three in this instance

Answer (score 0):

One table is probably the way to handle it in this case. If all images X have all sizes and you probably aren't likely to be adding tons of different sizes.

The three table would work just as well, but why deal with the joins when you don't really gain much.

```
Images
    ImageDetailsId (PK)
    ImageSizeId (PK)
    URL
    ...

Image_Details
   ImageDetailsId
   ...

Image_Sizes (where this table is relatively static - small, medium, large..)
   ImageSizeID
   ... (width? height? etc?)
```

Comment: Really... In this design... for every combination of `Image_Size` & `Image_Details` you have to repeat all attributes...

Comment: Image_Details has one record, for each Images (different sizes) you are linking to the Image_Details record and the Image_Size (essentially small / medium / large etc). So no, this is basically the one table solution cut into three - which I think is unnecessary in this case